# SSIS Derived Column Replace Dates

Tags: sql-server, datetime, ssis

Overview of situation: I have two databases (one is DB2 and one is MSSQL) and I am using an SSIS package to feed from one to the other via jobs. In our SQL table, datetime fields were set up as SmallDateTime (years and years ago, cannot change at this point in time yet to DateTime). We are now getting dates that are coming through as year 2099 (1/1/2099) which fails as SmallDateTime can only go MaxDate of 06/06/2079 11:59:59.

My/our solution is to use the Derived Column transform to check the date, and if it is over year 2078, make it null. It was also advised that check for null before checking date.

I tried doing this,

```
[Derived Column Name] [Derived Column  ] [Expression]
[        MyDate     ] [Replace "MyDate"] [MyDate == "" ? NULL(DT_WSTR,5) : MyDate]
[    VerifiedDates  ] [Add As New Column] [VerifiedDates == YEAR((DT_DBDATE)MyDate) > = 2078 ? NULL(DT_WSTR,10) : MyDate]
```

But this did not work for two reasons. Not only was the expression wrong, it also would not allow me to replace the column of "MyDate" like I did in the first run. Can I not replace a column more than once? Do these tasks happen at the same time?

Due to that issue, I tried to just replace the dates via the expression

```
[    MyDate    ][Replace "MyDate"][YEAR((DT_DBDATE)MyDate) >= 2078 ? NULL(DT_WSTR, 10) : MyDate]
```

as well as

```
[    MyDate    ][Replace "MyDate"][MyDate == YEAR((DT_DBDATE)MyDate) >= 2078 ? NULL(DT_WSTR, 10) : MyDate]
```

But none of these seem to be the correct syntax... Can anyone point me to where I am off?

I'm also having trouble finding a good resource for the syntax, presently using [this ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141721(v=sql.100).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the `DATEPART` function instead

```
[    MyDate    ][Replace "MyDate"][ DATEPART("yyyy", (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)MyDate) >= 2078 ? NULL(DT_WSTR, 10) : MyDate ]
```

Comment: I'll try that now; one sec

Comment: This seems to work for me thanks! I did have to alter it to be DT_DBDATE instead of timestamp as it threw overflow error. Thank you so much :D